# How to override xhtml theme css?

Tags: css, struts2, themes

I want to override some style provided in struts/xhtml/style.css. One of them is label style.
In struts/xhtml/style.css the label class is defined like this on line 23:

```
.label {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

In my style file, i redefined label style using the following class:

```
.label {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
    font-size:12px;
    width:150px;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

But my label is always in italic, when i use debug tools i see it's take xhtml property and does not override the property. Here is my complete css file :

```
/* Reset des properties */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    /*font: inherit;*/
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*Definition des properties pour le projet OCC*/
/*tags html*/
body{
    margin: auto;
    padding:auto;
    align:center;
    width:995px;
    font-family:Arial,"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

h1{}
h2{}
p{
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
li a {
font-weight:bold;
margin: 50px 0 ;
padding:5px;
}
/*div*/

#content{
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    text-align:justify;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#header{
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}


#headerButton{
    background-color:#6993C9;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    height:2px;
    width:auto;
    padding: 7px 10px 34px 10px;
}

#headerButton a:link:first-child{
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0  0 0 10px;
}
#headerButton a:link{
    color:#ffffff;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:11px;
}
#headerButton a:hover:first-child{
    color:#e6e6e6;
    margin: 0  0 0 10px;
}

#headerButton a:hover{
    color:#e6e6e6;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#imageOrange24{
margin:0 5px -10px 0;
padding: 0 0 0 0;

}

#formWrapper{
margin:50px auto 50px auto;
padding:50px 50px 50px 50px;
width:300px;
}



#formWrapper  tr{
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
#wwFormTable tr{
margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#menu{
    float:left;
    width:125px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#adminMessageBox{

    float:left;
    border: 2px blue solid;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;

}
#waitingActionBox{
    float:right;
    border: 2px blue solid;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;

}

/*div englobant la liste des brochures*/
#listeBrochures{

}

#search{
margin:0 0 20px 10px;
}
#dateCreation{

    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
/*classes*/
.fontGeneralTitle{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#6993C9;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.formLogin {
    font-family: Arial,Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-border-radius: 70px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.inputs {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #333;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
    font-size:12px;
    width:150px;
    font-style:normal;
}

.boutonLogin {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color:#f79646;
    color:#ffffff;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    behavior: url(/css/rounded/border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.tdLabel{

}


.boxTitle{
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blue;
    text-align:center;
    margin:10px 0;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.auteur{
    float:right;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.center{
    text-align:center;
}

.alignleft{
    float:left;
    margin:20px 0 50px 10px;
}
.alignright{
    margin:20px 100px 0 0;
}

.bold{
    font-weigth:bold;
    line-height:1;
}
.clear{
    float:clear;
}
.floatLeft{
    float:left;
}
.floatRight{
    float:right;
}
```

Here is my generated html form :

```
<div id="formWrapper"> 

        <form id="LoginAction" name="LoginAction" action="/OCC/LoginAction.action" method="post">
<table class="wwFormTable">
            <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="LoginAction_login" class="label">Identifiant: /label></td>
    <td
><input type="text" name="login" size="20" value="" id="LoginAction_login" class="inputs" title="Entrer votre identifiant"/></td>
</tr>

            <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="LoginAction_password" class="label">Mot de passe:</label></td>
    <td
><input type="password" name="password" size="20" id="LoginAction_password" class="inputs" title="Entrer votre mot de passe"/></td>
</tr>

            <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="LoginAction_0" value="Valider" class="boutonLogin" title="Cliquer pour se connecter"/>
</div></td>
</tr>

        </table></form>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Struts documentation about overriding is here : http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/struts-2-themes.html . Do i miss something ?

Comment: if its giving you too much trouble, go with simple theme and you are free to use your CSS as our own way

Comment: Where/how do you include your CSS? In other words, what's the `<head>` section look like? Are you including your CSS in a reasonable order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
.label {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333;
    font-size:12px;
    width:150px;
    font-style:normal !important;
}
```

The !important annotation should override the style.

Comment: Thank you jedrus07.It works. I did not know this property before. I am new in CSS.